# MIDlet not running. Failed to initialize connection with emulator 6

Tags: java-me, emulation, netbeans-7, midlet

**I'm trying to run a simple midlet on Java ME SDK 3.0 integrated into Netbeans 7.1 on Windows 7 Ultimate (just a UI). It was running fine until yesterday but now its showing an error and i can't see the midlet in the emulator. I don't think its anything related to compatibility issues because the applications were running just fine the other day. Could someone help me rectify this glitch or whatever it is?** (No error in program i guess)

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class Facebook extends MIDlet {

public void startApp() {
Form f = new Form("Facebook Login");
try {
Image g = Image.createImage("/Facebook 2.png");
ImageItem img = new ImageItem(null, g, Item.LAYOUT_CENTER, null, Item.PLAIN);
f.append(img);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
TextField tf = new TextField("Email or Phone", null, 300, TextField.ANY);
f.append(tf);
TextField tf1 = new TextField("Password", null, 300, TextField.ANY);
f.append(tf1);
ChoiceGroup cg = new ChoiceGroup(null, ChoiceGroup.MULTIPLE);
cg.append("Remember Me",null);
f.append(cg);
StringItem str = new StringItem(null, "Forgot Password?", StringItem.HYPERLINK);
f.append(str);
try {
Image g2 = Image.createImage("/Fb Login 2.png");
ImageItem img2 = new ImageItem(null, null, Item.LAYOUT_CENTER, null, Item.BUTTON);
f.append(img2);
} catch (IOException e2) {
e2.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}
}
```

Message in output:

Starting emulator in execution mode
*** Error ***
Failed to connect to device 6!
Reason:
Failed to initialize connection with emulator 6! (possible runtime incompatibility)
F:\NetBeansProjects\MobileApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)

Comment: The emulator works fine without an internet connection now. Could anyone enlighten me about it?